# Android Studio fails building project in task mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to move my project from Eclipse to Android Studio.
After creating all the modules (the app has a few library project), Gradle fails with this error all the time:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':AppLib:mergeDebugResources'.
> Unsupported type 'database' in file C:\Android\Code\AS_workspace\SuperApp\Infra\src\main\res\values\database.xml
```

This XML file is defined in a library project and is overridden with the same name in the app module.

Needles to say this works perfectly well in Eclipse for ages...

Any idea?

Thanks.

Adding the build.gradle files:

This is the app file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.superapp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library1')
}
```

This is the file for module :library1 which is an android library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library2')
}
```

This is the file for module :library2 which is also a library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':AppLib')
}
```

And now for the library for AppLib:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':GooglePlayServices')
    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

I have a lot of libraries but once I'll fully understand Gradle's flavor I'll be able to decrease them to two modules.

Database.xml in the AppLib is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="NAME" format="string" type="database"/>
    <item name="TABLE_NAME" format="string" type="database"/>
    <item name="DATABASE_VERSION" format="integer" type="database">101</item>
    <item name="MIN_APPLICATION_DATABASE_VERSION" format="integer" type="database">10</item>

</resources>
```

Database.xml in the SuperApp just adds the strings.

Comment: Can you show your app's build.gradle code?

Comment: @Lukos, for the whole project, the library app or the main app?

Comment: All three would be the quickest to solve, I have a feeling it might be in the library but I can't be sure.

Comment: Although, most of the time it turns out to be the app gradle.

Comment: @Lukos, added the build.gradle files. Thanks. They aren't really special now as I'm still not using gradle to the fullest. So it's really just dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, can you also show your database.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This apparently happens because android studio doesn't go well with "custom" type like I put "database".
After making it to strings and integers I worked.

Don't know why in Eclipse it's OK but AS complains.

Comment: please explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962

above deals with transitive library dependencies. Its long , not quite exactly to your point  over the collision on a name value, but you may want to check it out .

I would try using the project import dialog in AS 0.8.14+ which is pretty good with transitive dependencies among Libraries... Dont worry about coding the 'build.gradles' and their details. Rather let the importer give it a whack and then, if it will not build sucessful, go back to the details on the issue link above and try something like:

```
 releaseCompile project(path: '..:$Path-to-Library1', configuration: 'release')
 debugCompile project(path: '..:$Path-to-Library1', configuration: 'debug')
```

and same for your 'Library2'

Assumes:  that your eclipse.project.properties like below to guide AS importer...

```
android.library.reference.1=../Library1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify using a newer gradle version in your app build.gradle.

Ex:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.3'

    }
}
```

Older gradle versions give the mergeDebugResources error a lot more often.

Comment: Maybe also try to clean and rebuild your project, sometimes that helps.

Comment: I'm using a new gradle version.0.13.2. Anyway, clean and rebuild didn't help.

Comment: Did you put the classpath for that gradle dependency in your build.gradle? I don't see it.

Comment: Yes. It was generated automatically when I created the project. Also, all the gradle tasks before that one, is working fine.